# Do I need an amp if I'm using a PHAT DAC on my Pi Zero?

Tags: pi-zero, radio

I've bought a Pimoroni PHAT DAC for my Raspberry pi zero and despite weeks of searching I can't find a definitive answer on whether I need to get an amp breakout board too like this guy http://frederickvandenbosch.be/?p=1447 (although he's using it to convert the signal to mono and I'd like to keep stereo) to build an Internet radio.

Do I need a https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/adafruit-stereo-3-7w-class-d-audio-amplifier or will the PHAT DAC be enough to power speakers soldered directly to the DAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [product description](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/phat-dac) reads (among its other specs): *Line out stereo jack*. So it outputs [*Line Level*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) signals which are supposed to transmit analog audio signals between components and not to drive speakers. Connecting passive speakers (no integrated amp) at their low impedance (4 to 8 Ω) is not recommended. Their load is significantly lower (almost a short circuit) than the impedance line out is supposed to drive (10 kΩ) which results in a very weak signal and even possible damage of the line out circuit.

**Go for an audio amplifier.**

Comment: Of course you can get [Powered speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_speakers) that have a built-in amplifier - but beware of ones that have the option to be "switched-off" to connect the load of the un-amplified speakers direct to the, typically 3.5mm Stereo Jack Plug ended input lead...!